# passing a property to get it's value (as an expression?)

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I am thinking I should be able to use some sort of Expression as the argument for the final method below, but I haven't been able to work it out.

How can I do this?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
class Detail{
    string DisplayName{get;set;}
    string SpanishName{get;set;}
    string FrenchName{get;set;}
}

class Master{
    IEnumerable<Detail> AllDetail{get;set;}
    bool DoSpanish(get;set;)
    bool DoFrench(get;set;)

    _flipDisplayName(){
        DoSpanish 
            ? _flipDisplayName(x=>x.SpanishName) 
            : _flipDisplayName(x=>x.FrenchName);
    }

    // *****************************************************
    _flipDisplayName(????){ <==== Expression??
            foreach(Detail detail in AllDetail) detail.DisplayName = ???;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
_flipDisplayName(Func<Detail, string> name){ 
     foreach(Detail detail in AllDetail)
         detail.DisplayName = name(detail); 
}
```

Since you do not need to analyze the passed in expression, a `Func<,>` is sufficient.

You could also use `Expression<Func<,>>` which would allow you to parse the provided expression to figure out if it refers to the English or Spanish property but this is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goals correctly, you can do:

```
private void _flipDisplayName(Func<Detail, string> displayFunc)
{
        foreach(Detail detail in AllDetail) 
            detail.displayFunc(detail);
}
```

The other overload could then be:

```
private void _flipDisplayName()
{
    this.DoSpanish ? _flipDisplayName(x => x.SpanishName) 
                   : _flipDisplayName(x => x.FrenchName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Get value from ASP.NET MVC Lambda Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813340/get-value-from-asp-net-mvc-lambda-expression).  That is in the context of MVC, but the answer is applicable anywhere.

Comment: Marcind is right - I've answered the question you actually asked but he's answering what you actually need :)