# How can I take a string expression passed in lambdaExpression and convert it to DateTime?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, recursion, serialization

```cs
var serializer = new ExpressionSerializer(new Serialize.Linq.Serializers.JsonSerializer());
var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)serializer.DeserializeText(pageRequest.Predicate);
predicate = (Expression<Func<OrganisationItem, bool>>)lambdaExpression;
```

From the `UI` side, I take predicate with `PredicateBuilder`, serialize it with `Linq.Serialization` library and send it to the API. I'm decoding the series as above in api. I need to take my `UpdatedDate` field from this series and convert it to `DateTime`.

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not try it before, Maybe you can refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813340/get-value-from-asp-net-mvc-lambda-expression)

Comment: What is `UpdatedDate`? Where is it in your code?